# mailcatcher CakeEmailを使って本文を入れるとmailcatcherが落ちる

Tags: php, ruby, cakephp

cakePHPのブロジェクトにてmailcatcherを使いたいのですが、
本文を入れた送信が出来ません。

環境は仮想環境で動かし（VirtualBox Vagrant)テストしています。
cakephp 2.x

ホストは　Mac OS X 10.10.4

仮想環境(Ubuntu14.04)に入っているバージョンは
daemons (1.2.3)
eventmachine (1.0.5)
i18n (0.7.0)
mail (2.6.3)
mailcatcher (0.6.1)

Smtp送信設定
--email.php--

```
public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'from' => 'hoge@hoge.info',
    'port' => 1025,
);
```

設定はなんとかうまくいき、[http://ホスト名:1080](http://%E3%83%9B%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D:1080) で画面も見れます。

本文がないメール（タイトルのみ）の場合は送信出来て、
画面でもメールを確認出来ます。

が、本文を入れると、mailcatcher自体が落ちてしまいます。
（cakePHPの方では特にエラーは出ません）

Smtpの設定をgoogleにして送信してみるときちんと本文が入ったメールが届きます。

数日ハマってます・・

ちなみに cakephpの送信ソースは

```
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
$email->to($data['invitee']);
$email->subject(__('Invitation mail'));
$email->template('invitation');
$email->emailFormat('text');
$email->viewVars($data);
$email->send();
```

mailcatcherのエラーログもどれなのかよくわからず・・

テンプレートを使った場合はうまく行かないのでしょうか？

そもそも運用されているソース（メールは届いている）ので、
cakephp側の修正が必要だと厳しいのですが、原因がわかると助かります。

メールが飛ぶのをドキドキしないでテスト出来る環境が作りたい（；；）

mailcatcherの設定や、バージョンの問題など、何か情報があればよろしくお願いします。

Comment: タイトルに日本語を入れてもきちんと表示されています

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mailcatcher 0.6.1には、UTF-8のマルチバイト文字列の取り扱いにバグがあり、本文を表示すると華麗に落ちてくれます。

参考:
https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/201

修正されるまで、バージョン0.5.12を使用するようにしてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
maicatcherのバージョンの問題だったとは・・
早速、0.5.12にしてみたのですが、今度はSMTP timeout.になってしまいました。
これは、検索時によく見かけた、eventmachineのバージョンの問題と思い、バージョンを1.0.3にしようとしたのですが、いろいろうまくいかず・・
ruby、gemなどをインストールするのが初めてで苦戦しております。。
とりあえず原因が分かったので、mailcatcher0.5.12に合わせて他のバージョンを変更してみようと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちなみに私はmailcatcherは0.6.1のままでメール本文をbase64エンコードで送信するようにしていたりします。 参考: 
http://tipshare.info/view/4f63020f7f8b9a0a0b000001

Comment: そういう方法もあるんですね！ありがとうございます。
リンク参考にさせていただきます。